What is the best way to partition Ubuntu22 with Packer (and ansible?)
I have this all working, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? It seems very difficult to make small changes this way. I'm using the vsphere-iso provisioner here, but I can also work off a template if that makes sense. I'd like to avoid the extra step.
Ideally, I'd like to do this with Ansible, I'm just not sure of the best way.
I build the image with Packer and Ansible and SHell. Provision with Terraform and Ansible. So please give me advice on where the best place to do this is.
The thing i'm trying to do is set up LVM partitions in Ubuntu22. For EL I just do this with Kickstart.
In my ./http/user-data I have something like this
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/sda
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      id: disk-sda
      type: disk
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1048576
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 1048576
      path: /dev/sda1
      id: partition-0
      type: partition
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 2147483648
      wipe: superblock
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2097152
      path: /dev/sda2
      id: partition-1
      type: partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      id: format-0
      type: format
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 105223553024
      wipe: superblock
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2149580800
      path: /dev/sda3
      id: partition-2
      type: partition
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
      type: lvm_volgroup
    - name: root-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 21474836480B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/root-lv
      id: lvm_partition-0
      type: lvm_partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      id: format-2
      type: format
    - path: /
      device: format-2
      id: mount-2
      type: mount
    - name: tmp
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 5368709120B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/tmp
      id: lvm_partition-1
      type: lvm_partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-1
      preserve: false
      id: format-3
      type: format
    - path: /tmp
      device: format-3
      id: mount-3
      type: mount
    - name: home-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 10737418240B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/home-lv
      id: lvm_partition-2
      type: lvm_partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-2
      preserve: false
      id: format-4
      type: format
    - path: /home
      device: format-4
      id: mount-4
      type: mount
    - name: var-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 21474836480B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/var-lv
      id: lvm_partition-3
      type: lvm_partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-3
      preserve: false
      id: format-5
      type: format
    - path: /var
      device: format-5
      id: mount-5
      type: mount
    - name: log-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 10737418240B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/log-lv
      id: lvm_partition-4
      type: lvm_partition
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-4
      preserve: false
      id: format-6
      type: format
    - path: /var/log
      device: format-6
      id: mount-6
      type: mount
    - path: /boot
      device: format-0
      id: mount-0
      type: mount

It's obviously, not the best thing to have to modify. Are there better ways to specify partition layout?

You could use a single BTRFS partition with quotas and without using LVM at all.
